# QNetworkAccessManager and HTTP persistent connection

Tags: qt, qt4, pyqt, pyqt4, pyside

HTTP 1.1 supports persistent connection by default, so I want to send my a second http request using the same connection that was setup when the first HTTP request was made. how can this be achieved through Qt?

If I simply make the second request after the first one finished like the following

```
manager->get(QNetworkRequest(QUrl("http://qt-project.org")));
```

it seems a new TCP connection to the server will be initiated (I have checked with a network sniffer)
The experiment also says: If the reply is deleteLater() or abort() within
finished() signal, the connection will be closed.

Comment: You are showing C++ code yet "pyqqt pyqt4 pyside" are included in the tags. Please provide an reproducible code sample; it is possible that the persistent connection setting is not being set correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following to investigate further:

- Dump the HTTP headers (known and raw) of the outgoing request. You should see a `Connection: Keep-Alive` header set.
- Dump the response headers. There should ***not*** be a `Connection: Close` set by the webserver

Sometimes webservers don't honor the `keep-alive` header and will send a `close` anyway. In this case the client is rightfully closing the connection.

Comment: "Connection:keep-alive"  is in the  response header.

 I want to send my a second http request using the same connection that was setup when the first HTTP request was made. how can this be achieved through Qt?

Comment: Actually, you **shouldn't** have to do anything for sending the next request on the same connection  (**to the same host**), as Qt will internally reuse the TCP connection. Can you also check from the sniffer as to who is sending the TCP **`FIN`** packet first, client or server?

Comment: 1)where can I see the explanation of Qt internally reusing the TCP connection? 2)if I don't close() or deleteLater() the reply, neither client or server send the TCP FIN packet.

Comment: Try [this](http://peter.hartmann.tk/blog/2012/02/inside-the-qt-http-stack.html) link. It explains the innards of the Qt n/w stack.

Comment: @Mandeep Good link! It's moved [here](http://www.peter.hartmann.tk/#!Inside-the-Qt-HTTP-stack/cmzt/1)