# Does qtwebkit load complete page in single shot?

Tags: c++, http, qtwebkit

I'm using qtwebkit for HTTP request,

Does qt-webkit load http page in single shot? Does Qt-webkit creates separate requested for java script(.js), style sheet (.css), image links?

If it create separate request for this links, do we have access/control over that request?

Comment: How could it load .js and .css files in the same request as the html page, as the links are inside the html and not known before downloading it?

Comment: @galinette agreed but How it creates new request to load .js, .css ot .png files? Do any one know how to get access to those subsequent requests?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, single HTTP request fetches single file. So there are multiple requests anyway.
Second, a single TCP connection could be re-used - a persistent one. 
See [QNetworkAccessManager and HTTP persistent connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20162767/qnetworkaccessmanager-and-http-persistent-connection) for more info.